# Converting Hive HQL Map<string,string> into SQL Record Key Value

Tags: sql, hive

I have the following situation in Hive.
I have a map, called 'out', and I run this query.

```
  select distinct coalesce(out["a"],aa_out["b"]) b, 'id' b_name
  from TABLE
```

I have the exact same data in SQL, only this time my data appears as:

```
out RECORD  REPEATED    
out. key    STRING  NULLABLE    
out. value  STRING  NULLABLE
```

I want to write the exact same query in SQL. However I am not sure how to efficiently do that same Hive [ ] map notation in SQL with a Key Value record.

Any idea (Bigquery)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT distinct out_expanded.value b, 'id' b_name, from TABLE, 
UNNEST(out) as out_expanded 
WHERE coalesce(out_expanded.key = 'a', out_expanded.key = 'b');
```